# Play apple music playlist through 3rd party app?

Tags: apple-music

I am building a 3rd party app that can playback Apple Music. I know that this can be done for individual tracks, can I also queue up an existing public Apple Music playlist on my 3rd party app?

Comment: Have you found out anything here?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=05122016a